# Passing a string from python to rust via SWIG

Tags: python, rust, swig, swig-typemap

I'm working on building a library in rust that I think would be extremely useful in other languages.  I would like to expose this functionality with idiomatic bindings to as many languages as possible with as little effort as I can get away with.  Obviously SWIG is a great choice for this project.

I'm using a fantastic project called safer_ffi to produce the C interface to the rust library.  It removes a lot of the error prone boiler plate on the rust side but also limits my options on exactly what the C interface looks like.  Currently it represents strings with this C type:

```
typedef struct {
uint8_t * ptr;
size_t len;
} slice_boxed_uint8_t;
```

I can't for the life of me set the ptr member of the struct without causing a TypeError in python.  My interface file is simply:

```
%module swig_example
%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "swig_example.h"
%}

%include "stdint.i"
%include "cstring.i"

/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "swig_example.h"
```

and I try and set up the struct with the following python:

```
def _str_to_slice(input: str) -> slice_boxed_uint8_t:
    slice = slice_boxed_uint8_t()
    slice.ptr = input
    slice.len = len(input)
    return slice
```

which produces the following error "TypeError: in method 'slice_boxed_uint8_t_ptr_set', argument 2 of type 'uint8_t *'".  I have tried all sorts of combinations of how to invoke it and how to generate the bindings.  I've been walking through the generated C code but haven't found the issue yet. It looks like it understands that this pointer is a char* but isn't making the connection that it is okay to use as a uint8_t*.  I might have misunderstood some of the generated C code, I'm still not very deep on walking through that yet.

I did my best to include all relevant info but I know I might be missing some important context in this post so the code can be found [here](https://github.com/stusmall/python_ffi/tree/8d14ce5dbec093fed6c18c0a1d710d649b328167).  The README.md points out here to find all relevant files, reasoning on how things are set up and I checked in the SWIG generated c and python files.  This project is the smallest subset of my original project I could make to it easier for others to troubleshoot

Huge thank you to any help that anyone can provide!